# finding multiple alike values in items in a list

Tags: vb.net, list

i am writing a poker game, it will deal you different cards and then adds the dealt cards to a list. its a list of cards, each card has a value, cardno, which stores the number, what i need to do is check the list for say a straight (4,5,6,7,8 of clubs) or a full house (5 club, 5 diamond, 7heart ,7 spade, 7 diamond) and so on.

heres my cards code:

```
Public Class card
    Public suite As String
    Public cardlet As String
    Public cardno As Integer
End Class
```

and then i added it to a list

```
dim dealtcards as new list(Of card)
```

so i need to check if dealtcards contains a pair, two pair, three of a kind, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is create different 'functions' that look if a hand contains a certain combination. You can search for values in Arrays with this function:

```
Public Shared Function FindValueFromArray(ByVal Values As Object(), ByVal valueToSearch As Object) As Boolean 
    Dim retVal As Boolean = False 
    Dim myArray As Array = DirectCast(Values, Array) 
    If Array.IndexOf(myArray, valueToSearch) <> -1 Then 
        retVal = True 
    End If 
    Return retVal 
End Function
```

From [here](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/308-find-value-from-array.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need another class... `Public Class Hand`.

It could internally contain a list of cards, but the main point is the public interface it presents.  Methods to manipulate the list of cards (add to hand, remove from hand) and a method to check for a "status" of the hand (which could return a strongly-typed enumeration of known statuses).  Something not unlike this perhaps (my VB is *very* rusty, so this is mostly pseudo-code):

```
Public Class Hand
    Private cards As IList(Of card)

    ' A method to add a card to the hand, which should check if the hand can hold another card or not

    ' A method to remove a card from the hand, perhaps?

    ' Other methods representing actions that can be performed, such as folding the hand

    Public Function GetHandStatus As HandStatus
        If HandIsFlush() Then
            Return HandStatus.Flush
        Else If HandIsStraight() Then
            Return HandStatus.Straight
        End IF
    End Function

    Private Function HandIsFlush As Boolean
        ' loop through cards, return true if they are all the same suit
    End Function

    Private Function HandIsStraight As Boolean
        ' iterate through sorted-by-value cards, return false if more than 1 value separates any two
    End Function
End Class
```

What this is doing is reducing each element of business logic for this application into a single function to handle that logic.  If the class starts to get large, you can further refactor it, perhaps changing `HandStatus` from an enumeration into an abstract class with subclasses representing the statuses, and moving logic onto there.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create and dictionary of lambdas where the key is the type of hand you have and the lambda is the actual used to determine what time of hand.

```
Dim fullHouse = Function(cards as List(of Card)
                     //logic to check
                     return True or False
                End Function

Dim rules as New Dictionary(of String, func(of List(Of Card,Boolean))
rules.Add("FullHouse",fullHouse)

Dim hand as List(of Card)

DIm typeOfHand _
rules.
   Keys.
   Select(Function(k)
             If rules.Item(k)(hand) = True then Return k
             Return string.Empty).
   Where(Function(r) Not String.IsEmptyOrNull(r)).
   FirstOrDefault()

Dim score = hand.Select(h) h.CardNo).Sum()
```

Of course you can expand upon this example with more OOP but I think the use to lambdas and Linq with a functional approach will make it easier to understand and maintain your code.